# How can I reproducibly (py)test the failure mode of code that opens a file if the file is missing?

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to write a pytest case for the behavior of a function that opens a file in case that file does not exist.

I think the question boils down to a different one, namely "How can I be sure a file path does not exist on the file system?"

```py
import pytest

def file_content(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        return f.read()

def test_file_content_file_not_found():
    file_name_of_inexistent_file = "???"
    with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
        file_content(file_name_of_inexistent_file)

test_file_content_file_not_found()
```

`"???"` denotes the spot I think some great tool out there implements a reasonable and secure way to generate a file name or a mock file system that ensures the failure is guaranteed, but also doesn't need to change the file system.

At the moment, I have a small helper function that generates random strings that are tested if they are existing files and if they are not are returned. This way I can emulate the desired behavior. However, I guess there must be a more standard way to achieve this.

Comment: One could mock a file system with [PyFilesystem](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/guide.html) or a similar tool, but that would add a dependency to the code just for testing, which is not desirable.

Comment: Actually, you can just pass an empty string as a filename which will throw `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: @OlvinRoght This is a very elegant solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to use the builtin `tmp_path` fixture to generate a unique, empty directory:

```py
def test_does_not_exist(tmp_path):
    with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
        file_content(tmp_path.joinpath('dne'))
```

`tmp_path` is generated per-test and will start empty, so `dne` will never exist

if you want a generic, non-pytest solution you can use `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` directly:

```py
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
        file_content(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'dne'))
```

---

disclaimer: I'm a pytest core dev